# Can't access emails in Gmail labels

Tags: sync, 2.3-gingerbread, gmail, samsung-galaxy-s-2

This is a problem that suddenly appeared (or rather didn't!) on my Nexus One running Cyanogenmod 7.

It was fine and then all of a sudden I could no longer load any emails in any of the labels, it just says "loading conversations" but never loads or times out. Search is affected the same way.

I don't often have to use labels so I put up with it. However, it is still happening on my new Samsung Galaxy S2.

Choosing to sync specific labels for offline access means I can get to them fine, but it's impractical for all labels.

As suggested by Google mobile help I tried deleting the data for the Gmail app (though there is no additional "gmail mail storage" app)  and rebooting before re-syncing, to no avail.

During all this I have always been able to access labels on my 2.2 tablet and having just reinstalled CM7 on my Nexus One am now able to access them fine.

Any ideas?

Comment: Well, looks like the issue resolved itself, though I'm at a complete loss as to how. If anyone has any ideas, I'd still be interested in case it happens in future.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, so this problem reoccurred a couple more times until I realised it seemed to happen after my phone restarts and sorts itself out after killing a few running services I didn't need.

I narrowed it down to an app called Announcify.

The lesson for me, and others, is to try selectively killing services to troubleshoot any such problems in future.